# Realtime Ouput while PHP Function is Executing

Tags: php, ajax

My problem is that I need a PHP script to continously provide ouput at certein points of it's execution. I have workng AJAX to fetch the html but it only echos once the script is complete. Here is an example:

```
<?php 
class test {
     function test() {
          echo '1';
          sleep(20);
          echo '2'
          sleep(5);
     }
 }
```

I need some way to have the echo's actually displayed in the browser even though the function is still continuing. I have tried using global variables and session variables to no avail.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can use `flush()` but there is 0 guarantee this will work as you want - you need to reconsider the way you approach this

Comment: This is another XY problem. Why don't you expand the question by including *why* you need such a thing in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen many questions where people are trying to do this type of thing, but as far as I know it really isn't possible to do it the way you're trying to do it using only PHP and AJAX. In order for this to work using just AJAX rather than websockets or some other approach, you can break your script into separate pieces at the points where it needs to provide output, and provide the output as responses to separate AJAX requests. Here is a basic example of what I mean. The script on your page can start the process and makes repeated calls to step through the process until it's complete.

```
<button id="begin_process">Start</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function step(step_number) {
        $.get('test.php', {'step_number': step_number}, function(response){
            console.log(response.message);
            if (response.next_step) {
                step(response.next_step);
            }
        }, 'json');
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#begin_process').click(function(){
            console.log('go!');
            step(1);
        });
    });
</script>
```

test.php:

```
<?php 
class Test {
    function step($step_number) {
        switch ($step_number) {
            case 1:
                return array('next_step' => 2, 'message' => 'step 1 complete');
            case 2:
                sleep(20);
                return array('next_step' => 3, 'message' => 'step 2 complete');
            case 3:
                sleep(5);
                return array('message' => 'finished');
        }
    }

}
$test = new Test();
echo json_encode($test->step($_GET['step_number']));
```